# JAVA: (gestalt) pattern matching OR replacement for difflib.sequencematcher

Tags: java, pattern-matching

I am looking for a way to compare two Strings.
But not a simple equals().
I need some indicator of how likley it is that those to String matches. 
So for example (values are a guess not callculatated):

"Car" and "Car" retruns 1.0

"Car dog" and "Car" retruns 0.5

"Sitting" and "sit" retruns 0.45
etc.

Basically a replacement for: difflib.sqeuencematcher (http://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html) for Java.

I already looked @ java-diff-utils, but i didnt find a way to do that....

Comment: Match chars one by one, then divide by the length of the biggest (ignoring space) or whatever your weight calculation is.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Python's `difflib` is quite a bit smarter than that.

Comment: "Car dog" should not be a .5 because less than half of the strings match (" dog" is unmatched).

Comment: @larsman I don't doubt that. If the algorithm is available, OP can get inspiration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should have a look at Apache Commons Lang `StringUtils`. especially the [Levenshtein distance](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang//apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#getLevenshteinDistance%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29)

Comment: From reading the [`difflib`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher) docs, the algorithm used there is different from Levenshtein (=minimal edit distance): "This does not yield minimal edit sequences, but does tend to yield matches that “look right” to people."

Comment: Hmm, well it s not the same algo as difflib uses. But I guess it s the best possibility currently available in java. And i havent found a detailed enough description of the underlying algo to know if I could implement it myself!!

Answer (score 2):

To get a close approximation to what you are asking for you could use take the size of the string then StringUtils.remove your match attempt and then divide the original size minus the size remaining by the original size.

```
public double matchString(final String stringToMatch, final String matchPattern) {

    final int testSize = stringToMatch.length();


    if (testSize == 0 && matchPattern.length() == 0) {
        return 1.0;
    } else if (testSize == 0) {
        return 0.0;
    }

    final String remainderString = StringUtils.remove(stringToMatch, matchPattern);
    final int remainderSize = remainderString.length();

    final double result = (double) (testSize - remainderSize) / (double) testSize;

    return result;
}

@Test
public void testMatchString() {

    final double emptyResult = matchString("", "");

    final double delta = 0.01;
    Assert.assertEquals(1.0, emptyResult, delta);

    final double emptyCarResult = matchString("", "Car");
    Assert.assertEquals(0.0, emptyCarResult, delta);

    final double dogCatResult = matchString("CarDog", "Car");
    Assert.assertEquals(0.5, dogCatResult, delta);

    final double carResult = matchString("Car", "Car");
    Assert.assertEquals(1.0, carResult, delta);

    final double carsCarResult = matchString("Cars", "Car");
    Assert.assertEquals(0.75, carsCarResult, delta);

    final double sittingSitResult = matchString("Sitting", "Sit");
    Assert.assertEquals(0.4286, sittingSitResult, delta);

    // no match since the 'S' in Sitting is uppercased and is not in sit.
    // this can be fixed up lowercasing both the stringToMatch and matchPattern
    // in matchString
    final double sittingSit2Result = matchString("Sitting", "sit");
    Assert.assertEquals(0.0, sittingSit2Result, delta);

    // note the Sit match pattern matches two instences in 'Sit Sitting'
    final double sittingSit3Result = matchString("Sitter Sitting", "Sit");
    Assert.assertEquals(0.4286, sittingSit3Result, delta);
}
```